# Vuejs how to force v-model to update when Jquery changes text input?

Tags: jquery, vue.js, vuejs2, timepicker

I have 4 inputs with a timeselector popup. I'm using a jquery timepicker plugin that doesn't have any obvious way to manipulate an input via a callback. But Vuejs does not detect the changes to the text field even when they are clearly visible on the screen, until a key is pressed in the input field.

```
   <input data-ref="timeSelectionInput" v-model="item.StartTime"  type="text" data-ref="timeSelectionInput">
```

I tried this but it messed up and changes the values randomly to one of the other input fields.

```
  var timeSelectionInput = document.querySelectorAll("input[data-ref=timeSelectionInput]");
  for (let i = 0; i < timeSelectionInput.length; i++) {
    timeSelectionInput[i].dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
    console.log('input even dispatched')
  }
```

How are we supposed to update the model to match changes caused programmatically, and why is it so complicated on vuejs? It should just detect the change like Angular does with zones. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to access Vue's data object inside of the jQuery context. Which means it needs to be in scope. Below I demonstrate an approach.

Instead of the timepicker plugin I just used a button. I'm not sure how the timepicker plugin works specifically, but I'm sure there is a callback that fires on some sort of change event that you can use.

```js
let data = {
  value: 'initial',
};

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: data,
});

$(document).ready(function () {
  $('button').on('click', function () {
    data.value = 'changed';
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input v-model="value">  
</div>
<button>Change value via jQuery listener</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `changeTime` event to change your model, as in the examples provided here: http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/

```
$('#onselectExample').timepicker();
$('#onselectExample').on('changeTime', function() {
  this.selectedDate = $(this).val();
});
```

Alternatively using the lazy modifier could work, as it changes the update from `input` event to the `changed` event. This would mean that your model wouldn't update on `input` event anymore though.

```
   <input data-ref="timeSelectionInput" v-model.lazy="item.StartTime"  type="text" data-ref="timeSelectionInput">
```